# Deducing $\cos\theta\lt\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\lt 1$ from $\sin\theta \lt \theta \lt \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

My book states that using $$\sin\theta \lt \theta \lt \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$$ we can get $$\cos\theta\lt\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\lt 1$$
I tried with multiplying the first inequality by $\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$ but wouldn’t get the same result. Is there a mistake in my book or am I not seeing something?

Note. The book is proving the derivative of $\sin\theta$

Comment: Well, $\cos\theta < \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$ can't be true in general, because there are positive $\theta$ such that $\sin\theta$ is negative and $\cos\theta$ is positive.

Comment: You probably need that $\theta\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$

Comment: I think it's worth noting that (assuming $\theta\in(0,\frac{\pi}2)$ for the premise to be true in the first place), you're correct that $\sin\theta\cdot\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=\cos\theta<\theta\cdot\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}<\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\cdot\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=1$. So, you get the ends of inequality but not the $\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$ term in the middle, which you could partially infer from the given $\sin\theta<\theta$. You just needed to finish it off.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they have been pretty helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the second line comes from the second part of the first line, and vice versa.

From $\sin\theta<\theta,$ we get $\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\theta}<1$.

From $\theta<\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta},$ we get $\cos\theta<\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$.

Comment: I assumed these quantities are positive, so no need to reverse the inequality when multiplying or dividing by them

Comment: Oh boy, you are right, I only tried using the three terms together instead of in pairs like you just did. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, specifically, we probably want to restrict to $\theta\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}2\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Reverse

$$\sin\theta \lt \theta \lt \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$$

to get

$$\frac{\cos\theta}{ \sin\theta}\lt \frac 1\theta \lt \frac{1}{\sin\theta}$$

Then, multiply $\sin\theta>0$,

$$\cos\theta\lt\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\lt 1$$

Comment: Thank you, it’s a nice way to prove it.

Comment: @OctavioBerlanga - No problem.

Answer (score 1):

For $\theta\to0^+$, we have

\begin{array}{rcccl}
\sin\theta&\leq&\theta&\leq&\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\\
1&\leq&\dfrac{\theta}{\sin\theta}&\leq&\dfrac1{\cos\theta}&\text{(divide by }\sin\theta)\\
1&\geq&\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\theta}&\geq&\cos\theta&\text{(reciprocate)}
\end{array}

Or, when written in the *proper* order,
$$\cos\theta\leq\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\leq 1.$$

Comment: Thank you. your answer is right, I didn’t select it because somebody gave an answer before you. Yours is different so I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @OctavioBerlanga You will note that in order to evaluate the limit, you are required to use the inclusive inequality; otherwise you will end up with a statement that does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, I note that. Thanks.